# How does the Microprocessor detect if it's in-between an instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, microprocessors

I'm using an **ST32F401RE** (ARM Cortex -M4 32-bit RISC) and was curious about the following.

Normally instructions on a **32 bit ARM** can be 2 byte or 4 byte long.
I accidentally jumped in-between a 2 byte instruction and the Microprocessor instantly went into an infinite Error Handler loop afterwards.

I later tested this and jumped on purpose in-between a 4 byte and 2 byte instruction and the Microprocessor would always go into the Error Handler.

I used the following c code to jump into Memory Adresses.

```
void (*foo)(void) = (void (*)())0x80002e8;
foo( ) ;
```

The Adresses for functions and instructions are from the Disassembly.
The Compiler used the following assembler instruction after storing the adress in r3.

```
blx     r3
```

**Question:** How exactly can the Microprocessor tell that it didn't start at the beginning of an instruction but actually started in-between one?
Especially in case of the 16 bit thumb instructions which are already pretty cramped.

I have multiple guesses but want to know what exactly is going on.

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly how you "jumped". Have you looked up the relevant instruction in the ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual and read the description?

Comment: `void (*foo)(void) = (void (*)())0x80002e8; foo ();` this will always crash on a Cortex-M, as the address is even, indicating that the target instruction set is ARM (A32), which the Cortex-M don't support; but the `blx` instruction (`x` = exchange) requests the switch to ARM. You have to set the lowest bit in the address to indicate a jump to a Thumb instruction, or use the `bl` instruction (without exchange).

Comment: @Erlkoenig I also used the c goto when i tested this. It makes sense now, why the compiler added the `orr.w   r3, r3, #1` line.

Comment: Indirect go-to is a GCC extension anyways... Jumping to arbitrary addresses directly from C is always problematic. Better avoid it, or perhaps use (inline) assembly.

Comment: Maybe something like `__asm__ volatile ("blx %[fun]" : : [fun]"r"(0x80002e9) : "memory");` so you can directly control how the call/jump works. The address can be any C expression that yields a 32bit value.

Comment: my preference is a bit of real asm   .globl hop; hop: bx r0.   then from C void hop ( unsigned int );   and then hop(0x80002e9);   either way, best to take control because even with function pointers in a relatively language clean C way, can fail on the cortex-ms depending on how the code is and the compiler uses those addresses (which is why  you use or not add to set the lsbit if you force the lsbit)

Comment: naturally if you force the processor to fetch something that is not an instruction it will have unpredictable results (branching into the middle of a thumb2 instruction, which is no different than branching into the middle of random data).  there is no "detect" processors are very dumb they only do what you tell them, you feed them bits they process them if you feed them bad bits they fail.  they dont detect anything or have any knowledge of any of this stuff.  If you dont build the train tracks right and leave a gap or dont align them the trail will derail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally instructions on a 32 bit ARM can be 2 byte or 4 byte long.

Only for Thumb2; on Thumb they are all 2 bytes, and on ARM ("A32") mode they are all 4 bytes.

> Question: How exactly can the Microprocessor tell that it didn't start at the beginning of an instruction but actually started in-between one?

It can't. If the 2 upper bytes of a 4-byte instruction happen to form a valid 2-byte instruction and you jump there, it will be executed as such. In your case, these upper 2 bytes probably were all invalid instructions, resulting in a fault exception.

For example, the program

```
.code 16
.syntax unified

test4byte:
    mov.w r0, #0x88000000
    
test2byte:
    ands r0, r1
```

will be assembled into

```
00000000 <test4byte>:
   0:   f04f 4008   mov.w   r0, #2281701376 ; 0x88000000

00000004 <test2byte>:
   4:   4008        ands    r0, r1
```

or as a byte-wise hex dump

```
4f f0 08 40 08 40
```

As you see, the sequence `08 40` occurs twice - both as the upper 2 bytes of the `mov.w` and as the `ands` instruction, both of which are identical. So, the processor has no way to tell these apart.

In a program that just contained the shown `mov.w` instruction, if you jumped to address `0`, the `mov.w` would be executed; if you jumped to address `2`, an `ands` would be executed, even though it doesn't appear in the assembly code.